# TV show where characters have a short name, and they can't remember their real name

Tags: story-identification, tv

This is a show I used to watch around the 2000s, all or most characters had a short name like a number or a letter.
Generally, the show was in some alternate universe, maybe desert-like, but in the intro or one of the episodes, a character is seen on normal earth doing normal stuff.

The show was not a cartoon.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What made it an alternative universe?  How was it possible to tell?  Also, where were you when you watched this?  Was it in English?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: I have marked this question as a duplicate. That doesn't mean that it's a bad question, merely one that we've had before.

Comment: Another show that did this was [Dark Matter](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4159076/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0) (2015).  Not posting as an answer because it's definitely more space-opera sci-fi, not set on a planet most of the time.  One key difference is that in The Prisoner, the characters do presumably remember their real names, they're just not allowed to use them.  Whereas in Dark Matter they actually don't know and pick numbers based on the order in which they awoke on the ship.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have already had the suggestion that it was The Prisoner (1967)

As an alternative, the show had a [remake in 2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prisoner_(2009_miniseries)). I suspect the possibility that it is the remake you saw.

You say that "They can't remember their real name". This was true in the remake. The central character initially can't remember his former life.  In the original, names were forbidden, but there was no suggestion that they were forgotten.

You say that the place was "maybe desert-like"  The remake is set in a place surrounded by desert, while the original was set in a village on the coast.

You say that "in the intro or one of the episodes, a character is seen on normal earth doing normal stuff."  The remake has a number of flashbacks to the central character's life before he came to the village as he regains his memories.

Comment: I agree this is much more likely correct than the correct answer

Comment: And, for the record, I have no problem with the accepted answer being switched. :-D

Answer (score 13):

Might you be thinking of *[The Prisoner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prisoner)*?

> The series follows an unnamed British man (McGoohan) who, after abruptly and angrily resigning from his high-ranking government job – apparently a secret service post – prepares to make a hurried departure from the country. The most he will later reveal about his resignation is that it was a "matter of conscience".
>
> While packing his luggage, he is rendered unconscious by knockout gas piped into his London home. When he wakes, he finds himself in a re-creation of the interior of his home, located in a mysterious coastal "village" within which he is held captive, isolated from the mainland by mountains and sea.
>
> Although internal physical movement of residents around the Village is unconstrained, the premises are secured by numerous high-tech monitoring systems and security forces, including a balloon-like automaton called Rover, that recaptures or kills those who attempt escape. The man encounters the Village's population, hundreds of people from all walks of life and cultures, all seeming to be peacefully and mostly enjoyably living out their lives. **They do not use names, but have been assigned numbers which, aside from designations such as Two, Three, and Six, give no clue as to any person's status within the Village**, whether as prisoners or guards. Potential escapees, therefore, have no idea whom they can and cannot trust. The protagonist is assigned Number Six, but he repeatedly refuses the pretence of his new identity.

### Opening sequence

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly it!!

Comment: Always an upvote for *The Prisoner*.

Comment: There was a remake of The Prisoner in 2009.  In the remake the Village was surrounded by desert.  In the original it was on some coast, or possibly an island.   The OP's reference to the show being possibly set in a desert makes me suspect he saw the remake, not the original.  Can we reopen, so I can submit this as a possible answer.

Comment: @Pete: Done. Good call.

Answer (score 4):

Even though the wanted movie has already been found, this may be helpful to others who find this question.

The first thing that came to my mind when I read the question was *[Dollhouse](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1135300/)*, which ran two seasons in 2009.

In Dollhouse, people have their consciousness stored away for a couple of years and their bodies can be "rented" by other people. Every "doll" has a fairly short designation like Echo, Victor, Sierra, etc. and for every assignment a artificial consciousness is loaded into their brain, which has been tailored to the requirements of the customer. After the assignment it is complete, it is removed again. They don't know who they really are, until their contract with the company is up and their original consciousness is restored.

### Trailer

Comment: Note that the Dolls' names are all (as far as we know) from the “Alpha Bravo Charlie” alphabet.